# Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self?

Tags: java, html, security, web-applications, content-security-policy

I have Java-based based web application running on [Tomcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) 6. My application is running on localhost and port 9001.

To make my application more secure and to reduce the risk of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks, I added the header `Content-Security-Policy` with value **default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';script-src 'self'**. With this I want to allow the web application to load the JavaScript files from same domain.

For other resources it continues to load in the same fashion as it was without this header.

But I am getting the below error.

```
Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src http://localhost:9001").
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is causing the error you're seeing, but your `default-src` looks overly full: "Multiple source list values can be space seperated _with the exception of `*` and `none` which should be the only value_." (emphasis, mine) http://content-security-policy.com/#source_list

Comment: @kuporific sorry I did not get this. What should be the value in my case then ?

Comment: I had this problem when working with helmet library in nodejs, take a look at my answer in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70054564/11704057

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Content Security Policy header is a white list of trusted sources.

The `default-src` list is the list used by all other `*-src` lists. If it is not present, the default is `default-src: *` which means "all content is allowed from anywhere", which does not provide any protection against XSS.

Therefore, you should start with

- `default-src none`, so that all content is disallowed, or
- `default-src 'self'`, so that only content from your domain is allowed.

After that, other `*-src` can be replaced as needed. For example, the following trusts self for everything except images, and images are only allowed from example.com (but not from 'self'):

```
default-src 'self'; img-src example.com;
```

In your question, you specify `default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';` which might be causing the issue since `*` already implies `'unsafe-inline'` and `'unsafe-eval'`. It's like saying "allow everything and allow inline and allow eval".

Also note that CSP is supported via the `X-Content-Security-Header` in IE >= 8.

Sources:

- http://content-security-policy.com/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/
- http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy

Comment: I tried just script-src  'self' but it did not make any difference as I still get same error

Comment: Is there a way I can tell loading resource irrespective of protocol . I mean I want to load javascript resource from both `https://www.google-analytics.com http://www.google-analytics.com`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score -5):

Try:

```
default-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
```

Comment: @haywire It does look like an attempt to answer the question. It's a little thin, yes, but if you think, this answer is wrong or incomplete, you can downvote it.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.